# Query Only Show Text on Posts With Certain Taxonomy Tag

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-taxonomy, query

I am trying to query in a post to show a fixed line of text at the end, so that if that post has a specific taxonomy tag applied to it (Special), then a line of text will show.

I guess it's something simple, but  can't get a query to work :(

Would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `has_term` [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term), like the following code:

```
if( has_term( 'jazz', 'genre' ) ) {
    echo 'This is something...';
}
```

Remember to add the third parameter - $post (int or object), if it's not in the loop.

Comment: Great. Could you mark my answer as "accepted"? Thanks.